# predict vector values instead of single output

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression

In linear regression I've always seen the situation where I have many features and I use them to predict a single output, for example

```
f1 f2 f3 f4 --> y1
f1 f2 f3 f4 --> y2
```

and so on...
I want to know if there is something where the predicted value i.e. y1 is actually a vector not a single value

Answer (score 3):

Yes, pretty much every regression method (neural networks, support vector regressors, random forest regressors, ....) works just fine for multidimensional output. Including linear regression. In particular if y is N row and K column vector of values to predict, and X is N row, d column data matrix, linear reggresion is simply

```
A = (X'X)^-1 X'y
```

and then prediction is of form

```
XA
```

which is again N rows, K columns prediction matrix.