# Given inputs and outputs vector, which model is best for predicting unknown data?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, computer-vision

I don't have much experience with training neural networks. I have 4 variable vectors as input and I have respectively 3 variable output vector. I want to create a neural network that takes these inputs and outputs which have some unknown correlation(might not be linear) between them and train. So that when I put previously untrained data through it should predict the correlated output.

I was wondering,

1. What type of model should I use in such scenarios? Is it Restricted boltzmann machine, regression, GAN, etc?
2. What library is easiest to learn and implement for such a model? eg:- TensorFlow, PyTorch, etc
3. If images were involved which can be processed as fft arrays, would the model change.

I did find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36320991/predict-vector-values-instead-of-single-output), but I am not satisfied with it.
Please let me know if there are any functions or other points you would like me to know. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: There is no single best method. The only way to know which method is best for your problem/data is to try them all and compare.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I will take that in account @CrisLuengo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. A multilayer perceprton is a good place to start.
2. Keras is the highest level/easiest to use library I have used.
3. If you are working with images or spatially structured data a convolutional neural network will probably work best.

Comment: Yes, I will start running data through it, do you know any loss function that I can use to predict data between -10 to +10, or -infinity to +infinity?

Comment: You're going to want to normalize your labels into a certain range. A common method is subtracting the mean and dividing by the standard deviation. Try different ways of normalizing and different activation functions to see what works best. Keras makes it very easy to find the best settings.